# Linux variable inside string, using linux variables inside data pump query

Tags: linux, oracle, shell

I am trying to use oracle data pump to export rows of table because the table contains CLOB column and import them to another db. I have linux shell which is used to run the expdp query. The only thing is that for my query i want to select data after a period of time which i get this from db. So i have the **RETDATE** as a variable which is used to call sqlplus in order to get that value in the form of YYMM and then i will use it inside the data pump query.

My question is that **RETDATE** is a string can i have variables inside or should they be concatenated like for example in sql we use the || ?? For example i have

```
RETDATE=`sqlplus $USERNAME/$PASSWORD@$INSTANCE`
```

Username and Password are used to connect to the database and $INSTANCE is the dname but below i have

```
SELECT hire_date FROM table@$ANOTHERINSTANCE;
```

where $ANOTHERINSTANCE is the db link name used to get the value of the date.

The second part of the question is that if the TO_TIMESTAMP('$RETDATE','YYMM') valid inside the query. This is the code i am thinking to use. Will something like this work??

```
USERNAME=myname
PASSWORD=pass
INSTANCE=dbinstance
ANOTHERINSTANCE=dblinkname

RETDATE=`sqlplus $USERNAME/$PASSWORD@$INSTANCE <<EOF
SET PAGESIZE 0 FEEDBACK OFF VERIFY OFF HEADING OFF ECHO OFF
SELECT hire_date FROM table@$ANOTHERINSTANCE;
EXIT;
EOF`

QUERY='employees:"WHERE hire_date > TO_TIMESTAMP('$RETDATE','YYMM')"' 
PATH=/tmp/test
expdp $USERNAME/$PASSWORD@$INSTANCE directory=EXPORT_DIR tables=hr.employees query=$QUERY dumpfile=$PATH/employees.unl content=data_only logfile=employees.log
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a “linux variable”! Are you talking about `bash`?

Comment: Yes. When you are writing a .sh script and refer to a variable as RETDATE=something and you can echo using echo $RETDATE.

Comment: I don't think you can expand variables inside single quotes so you may have to use some string addition to build your QUERY.

Comment: Please correct me if i am wrong. The Retdate doesnt have a problem since its inside backticks. Or should i enclose in " the variables such as username pass instance qnd another instance. Now for the Query is the part where i have to concatenate strings in order to include the variable retdate but also preserve the single quotes